# SKSpriteNode action wait for complete another action

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I have some node with action, like this:

```
SKSpriteNode *randomSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:spriteName];
SKAction *action = [SKAction moveToY:0 duration:3.5];
[randomSprite runAction:[SKAction repeatAction:action count:1]];
```

In some place of code (not in same place where I create first) I create new node with another action

```
SKSpriteNode *anotherSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:spriteName];
SKAction *action = [SKAction moveToY:0 duration:0.5];
[anotherSprite runAction:[SKAction repeatAction:action count:1]];
```

but I need start action of second node only when first is complete his action how I can make it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can have the second sprite in a separate method, say

```
-(void)secondSpriteAction:(SKSpriteNode*)secondSprite{
  SKAction *action = [SKAction moveToY:0 duration:0.5];
  [secondSprite runAction:[SKAction repeatAction:action count:1]];
}
```

and make a selector for this method in the first sprite's action

```
SKAction *performSelector = [SKAction performSelector:@selector(secondSpriteAction:) onTarget:self];
```

and then you can add

```
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[action,performSelector]];
```

and instead of repeating the action, repeat the sequence

```
[randomSprite runAction:[SKAction repeatAction:sequence count:1]];
```

so something like this:

```
SKSpriteNode *randomSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:spriteName];
SKAction *action = [SKAction moveToY:0 duration:3.5];
SKAction *performSelector = [SKAction performSelector:@selector(secondSpriteAction:) onTarget:self];
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[action,performSelector]];
[randomSprite runAction:[SKAction repeatAction:sequence count:1]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `completion` block for `runAction:`

```
SKSpriteNode *randomSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:spriteName];
SKAction *action = [SKAction moveToY:0 duration:3.5];

[randomSprite runAction:[SKAction repeatAction:action count:1] completion:^{

    SKSpriteNode *anotherSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:spriteName];
    SKAction *action = [SKAction moveToY:0 duration:0.5];
    [anotherSprite runAction:[SKAction repeatAction:action count:1]];

}];
```

If you need to intialise anotherSprite in some other place in the code, you can put it in another method like Lamikins has suggested and call that method from the completion block.

Read up on the `runAction: completion:` method [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/runAction%3acompletion%3a).